# attempting to create a base64 download link

Tags: html, jsp, base64

I am attempting to download a pdf of base64 over an anchor tag from a jsp page. On clicking on the anchor tag it displays a blue screen and never loads the pdf. Here is my snippet

```
<a target="_blank" href="data:application/pdf;base64,${pdfdoc}">Download Link</a>
```

but previewing over an iframe the pdf renders well as shown below

```
<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='data:application/pdf;base64, ${pdfdoc}'></iframe>
```

please what am I doing wrongly

Comment: Could be a problem with "Top-level navigation blocked to data:// URIs" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs You can try to instead of using `target="_blank"` use  `download="name.pdf"`

Comment: I did this and its not clickable anymore>>> <a download="${pdfdoc}" href="data:application/pdf;${pdfdoc}">Download Link</a>